# Telerik.Web.UI could not be found, yet in project references

Tags: telerik, using-directives

I am trying to move some existing webforms over to a new Web Application project type and they make use of the Telerik AJAX UI controls. I have installed the Telerik package and gone through their configuration steps (i.e. Convert to Telerik  Web Application).

When I try and reference the controls via the `using` directive ...

`using Telerik.Web.UI;`

I get an error saying ..

`The type or namespace name 'Telerik' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

What is confusing me is that the project has the references to the Telerik DLLs as shown below.

[image]

Why can't they be referenced?

Answer (score 0):

This reference can point to a wrong location or version of the assembly.

Please remove the reference and add it again.

Note that all Telerik assemblies should be taken from the same installer.